# package javax.jnlp not in java.desktop ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, jre

Anybody solve this error?
I'm trying to run a Java application on Ubuntu, and I got this error:

```
$ javaws http://192.168.1.211:7777/forms/frmservlet/config=mmcs
selected jre: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
WARNING: package javax.jnlp not in java.desktop
```

[image: Error message]

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870810/the-import-javax-jnlp-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: @xenoid i had same issue and the link you provide did not help

Comment: please add the ubuntu version you are using and the java version to your question

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `browser` option and check the result:

```
$ javaws -browser http://192.168.1.211:7777/forms/frmservlet/config=mmcs
```